# NHibernate3 Query vs QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I noticed there are two ways to create nice generic friendly access to nhibernate.

```
IQueryOver<T, T> query= session.QueryOver<T>().Where(criteria);
```

and

```
IQueryable<T> query= session.Query<T>().Where(criteria);
```

Implementations of each interface.

```
IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> : IQueryOver<TRoot>, IQueryOver
```

and

```
IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

IQueryable implements IEnumerable, thus supports all the LINQ friendly things you would expect. I am tending towards this implementation, but was wondering if anyone knew what the purpose of QueryOver was that you cannot accomplish with Query?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Though there isn't a great amount of detail on the trade-offs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`QueryOver` combines extension methods and lambda expressions:

```
IList<Cat> cats =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .Where(c => c.Name == "Max")
        .List();
```

`QueryOver` is a strongly-typed querying technology built on top of NHibernate’s Criteria API.

You can read more info [here](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html) and [here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/nhibernate-queries.html).

As far as I know some features in the linq provider are not implemented yet.
I would use `QueryOver`.
It allows you to write elegant code and it is fully featured.

Something worth [reading](http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/03/13/queryover-series-part-1-why-queryover/).

Answer (score 16):

**QueryOver** syntax is NHibernate specific, thus it has many powerful methods that you just can't match in LINQ.

As LeftyX said, the LINQ implementation for NH is not complete, and I've had several headaches with it. For example, recently I had problems using the 2nd level cache, the Future values, and NH Spatial extensions with LINQ, all due to an incomplete implementation or bugs (and not mentioning the performance of some generated SQL, which is sometimes pretty awful).

In all these cases I had to use QueryOver, and after surpassing the learning-curve, is has, IMHO, a much nicer syntax than LINQ.

But LINQ via **Query** also has advantages; like being ORM agnostic (which might leverage a cleaner repository architecture), and for simple queries it is more than enough.