# What is the difference between NHibernate Query<> vs QueryOver<>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I just started with NHibernate (using SQLite) in my current project and I mostly used `Query<>`, because I was familiar writing db queries in Linq.

When I was confronted with some more complex queries, I did some research on `QueryOver<>` and figured that it should be favored over `Query<>` because *"QueryOver syntax is NH specific"*. Also, there seems to be nothing that `Query<>` can do that `QueryOver<>` can't accomplish.

So I began replacing all usages of `Query<>` accordingly. It wasn't long before I had the first "issue" where using `Query<>` seemed just more convenient.
Example (select highest value from column `CustomNumber` in table `BillingDataEntity`):

```
int result = Session.Query<BillingDataEntity>().Select(x => x.CustomNumber).OrderByDescending(a => a).FirstOrDefault();
int result = Session.QueryOver<BillingDataEntity>().Select(x => x.CustomNumber).OrderBy(a => a.CustomNumber).Desc.Take(1).SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

What I dislike is the need to explicitly cast the result to int and that the the Query<> version is just easier to read. Am i getting the query totally wrong, or in other words: Is there a better way to do it?

I took a look at the generated SQL output:

```
NHibernate: select billingdat0_.CustomNumber as col_0_0_ from "BillingDataEntity" billingdat0_ order by billingdat0_.CustomNumber desc limit 1
NHibernate: SELECT this_.CustomNumber as y0_ FROM "BillingDataEntity" this_ ORDER BY this_.CustomNumber desc limit @p0;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

What exactly am i looking at? Is this the "internal" (method dependent) query that NHibernate further translates into the actual database query?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are plenty of answers regarding QueryOver versus Query here on Stackoverflow but in a nutshell:-

> QueryOver is a strongly-typed version of Criteria, and is more
>   NHibernate specific. Pretty much anything you can do in ICriteria can
>   be done with QueryOver.  In the golden days of ICriteria NH2 you always had
>   to cast, hence this is why now you need to cast at the end of the
>   chain back to an int.
>
> LINQ (Query) is a standard query method that works on IQueryable that
>   doesn't need explicit references to NHibernate and can be considered
>   more ORM agnostic and therefore follows the linq standard. As you
>   rightly pointed out you do not need to cast to an int as you are
>   selecting into the result the customNumber.

I would be very surprised for your simple example if the generated SQL was very different.

I was a big fan of `QueryOver` but as the Linq provider is getting more mature then 95% of my queries I use `Query` but for some Nhibernate specific stuff I resort back down to `QueryOver`. Either way I recommend using a profiling tool to see what you can live with.

Refs: [Tradeoffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874012/tradeoffs-using-nhibernate-3-0-queryover-or-linq-provider) or [versus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328565/nhibernate3-query-vs-queryover) and [versus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328565/nhibernate3-query-vs-queryover)

Comment: I am not sure you can answer your first question directly as my answer points out that QueryOver is based on ICiteria and `this is the way it has to be done you are doing it correctly`. To view generated SQL I would use a commercial tool like NHProf as it is the best out there. Not meaning to be blunt and HTH clarifies the answer I have given.

Comment: Also, `Query<T>` returns an `IQueryable` which IS an `IEnumerable` so it's super convenient.

Comment: @Rippo: second and third link point to the same question

Answer (score 2):

About your QueryOver version, I would have written :

```
int result = Session.QueryOver<BillingDataEntity>()
               .Select(Projections.Max<BillingDataEntity>(x => x.CustomNumber))
               .SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

It seems quite readable, and the resulting SQL would be something like :

```
SELECT max(this_.CustomNumber) as y0_ FROM "BillingDataEntity" this_
```

Hope this will help