# NHibernate parent list with child count

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-to-linq-conversion

i am using NHibernate 4 with mysql. i have got 2 tables. My tables are cat and answer.

```
public class cat
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual string catName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<answer> answers { get; set; }
}

public class answer
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int catId { get; set; }
    public virtual string detail { get; set; }
    public virtual bool stat { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("catId")]
    public virtual cat cats { get; set; }
}
```

i want to select all cat record(with answer list) and with their cild answers count.

my sql query like that;

```
select count(t2.id) as count, cats.*from cat cats left join answer t2 ON(cats.id=t2.catId and t2.stat=0) GROUP BY(cats.id);
```

Result like this;

id - catName - count

1 - Book    - 5

2 - Pc      - 0

3 - English - 22

4 - Arts    - 56

i have try also this NH query;

```
public class myClass {
  public virtual int count { get; set; }
  public virtual cat cats { get; set; }
}

var u = db.CreateCriteria(typeof(cat), "cats")
       .CreateAlias("answer", "t2", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Eq("t2.stat", false))
      .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
      .Add(Projections.Count("t2.id"), "count")
      .Add(Projections.Group<cat>(g => g.id)));


var list = u.SetFetchMode("answer", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<myClass>())
        .List<myClass>();
```

This NHibernate query return also answers count. but cats always return null. How can i do my query for this result ?

**Edit 1**
i can do it like that

```
public class myClass {
  public virtual int count { get; set; }
  public virtual catId count { get; set; }
  public virtual cat cats { get; set; }
}


cat cats = null;
answer answers = null;

var u = db.QueryOver<cat>(() => cats)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.answers, () => answers, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Eq("answers.stat", false))
    .SelectList(cv => cv
        .SelectCount(() => answers.id)
        .SelectGroup(c => c.id))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(ax => new myClass
    {
      count = (int)ax[0],
      catId = (int)ax[1],
      cats = (cat)db.QueryOver<cat>().Where(w=>w.id==(int)ax[1]).Fetch(fe => fe.answers).Eager.SingleOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Small Offtopic hint: if you have the choice, get rid of the criteria api and use the [QueryOver or Query Api](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15020817/6666799) from NHibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can do that query like that;

```
public class myClass {
  public virtual int count { get; set; }
  public virtual İnt catId { get; set; }
  public virtual cat cats { get; set; }
}

cat cats = null;
answer answers = null;

var u = db.QueryOver<cat>(() => cats)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.answers, () => answers, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Eq("answers.stat", false))
    .SelectList(cv => cv
        .SelectCount(() => answers.id)
        .SelectGroup(c => c.id))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(ax => new myClass
    {
      count = (int)ax[0],
      catId = (int)ax[1],
      cats = (cat)db.QueryOver<cat>().Where(w=>w.id==(int)ax[1]).Fetch(fe=>fe.answers).Eager.SingleOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your result `cats` is always null, because the `ResultTransformer` tries to map the properties by their names.

Please check your NHibernate logfile. You will probably see that your query returns the columns `count` and `id`, but `myClass` has the properties `count` and `cats`.

**Edit:**

**New suggestion:**

The previous suggestion did not work, because the property `id` is of type `Int32` and cannot be assigned to `myClass.cat` (which is of type `cat`).

If you don't need a reference to a `cat`-object in `myClass` then you can change it to this:

```
public class myClass {
  public virtual int count { get; set; }
  public virtual int catId { get; set; }
}
```

and have the projection like this:

```
.Add(Projections.Group<cat>(g => g.id), "catId"));
```

If you do need a property of type `cat` in your result class I don't think this can be done with a simple projection but I might be wrong.

**Edit 2:**

Since you require an object of type `cat` in your result I suggest you put it together manually after the query, e.g.:

New result class:

```
public class myClassResult {
  public virtual int count { get; set; }
  public virtual cat cats { get; set; }
}
```

Add this after your query logic:

```
IList<myClassResult> result = new List<myClassResult>();
foreach (var idWithCount in list) 
{
  result.Add(new myClassResult() 
  {
    cats = catsOnlyList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == idWithCount.catId),
    count = idWithCount.count
  });
}
```

`catsOnlyList` refers to a simple list of cats that you need to get beforehand. I know this isn't pretty but I don't think you can group by `cat` itself in the query.

**Old suggestion** (does not work because of incompatible types):

Instead of

```
.Add(Projections.Group<cat>(g => g.id)));
```

use

```
.Add(Projections.Group<cat>(g => g.id), "cats"));
```

Comment: Florian Lim it's returning same columns. give this error : The type System.Int32 can not be assigned to a property of type cat

Comment: @ASPMaker Sorry, I didn't test the solution. I should have known this doesn't work, since grouping by ID will not get you a result property of type `cat`. I modified my answer.

Comment: i'am sorry but this change only give me id. i want for this query, it must return count of answer and cat table with children of answer. i explain all of them in my question.

Comment: @ASPMaker In that case you will have to put the result together manually. See my second edit.